# What is wrong with the PHP function in_array(...)?

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

The PHP function [`in_array(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) "checks if a value exists in an array".

But I'm observing a very strange behavior on handling strings (PHP `v7.0.3`). This code

```
$needle = 'a';
$haystacks = [['a'], ['b'], [123], [0]];
foreach ($haystacks as $haystack) {
    $needleIsInHaystack = in_array($needle, $haystack);
    var_dump($needleIsInHaystack);
}
```

generates following output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true) <- WHAT?
```

The function returns `true` for every `string` `$needle`, if the `$haystack` contains an element with the value `0`!

Is it really by design? Or is it a bug and should be reported?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you do not set the third parameter of [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/function.in-array.php) to true, comparison is done using type coercion.

> If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.

Under [loose comparison rules](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), effectively `'a'` is equal to `0` since `(int)'a' == 0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I didn't consider, that `'a' == 0` is `true`.

Comment: And it's even more crazy: While `'a' == 0` is `true`, `'1' == 0` IS `false` (because `(int) '1'` IS `1` and `1` IS NOT `0`).

Comment: `'a' == 0 IS TRUE`, `0 == null IS TRUE`, `null == 'a' IS FALSE`. If we replace the concrete values by variables, we'll see, that this behavior is illogical: `a = b`, `b = c`, `c <> a`.